# A session key is required for calling this method fbcmd?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

I am using fbcmd tool for facebook offline access.

fbcmd auth XXXXXX worked fine for a while.

Suddenly i am getting the following error

```
fbcmd [v1.0-beta5-dev1] ERROR: AUTH
[453] A session key is required for calling this method
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: This error occurs only when calling a rake task

```
require "#{Rails.root}/config/environment.rb"
namespace :posts do 
   desc "delivers expired posts"
   task :deliver do 
     postmessages = Postmessage.where(:expires_on=>(Time.zone.now-10.minutes)..(Time.zone.now))
     unless postmessages.empty?
       puts "Delivering posts..."
       postmessages.each do |postmessage|
             system("fbcmd auth 975NN1")
             system("fbcmd POST '#{postmessage.craft_message}'")
       end 
       p "Delivered posts"
    else
     p "No posts to deliver"
    end
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed your password or removed teh application from your privacy settings. If it is not working suddenly this is most likely the cause.

Comment: i did not changed my password or removed anything.I have started getting this error when running the code system("fbcmd auth XXXXXX") which is inside a rake task

Answer (score 0):

What method are you calling? Do you have a valid access token?

Comment: I have generated offline access token having 6 digit length.
fbcmd auth 'XXXXXX' displayed Welcome to FBCMD, Soundar Pandian!.
Even i have posted message.After sometime it showed this error.

Comment: I have started getting this error when running the code 
system("fbcmd auth XXXXXX") which is inside a rake task